# Basis and dimension of a subspace of $\mathcal{M}_{2\times 2}(\mathbb{R})$

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

Let $V=\mathcal{M}_{2\times 2}(\mathbb{R})$ is a space of square matrices of order $2$. Find the basis and dimension of a subspace $S\cap T$ and $S+T$ where $T=span\left\{
        \begin{bmatrix}
        2 & 0  \\
        1 & 3  \\
        \end{bmatrix}
,        \begin{bmatrix}
        1 & 9  \\
        6 & 2  \\
        \end{bmatrix},        \begin{bmatrix}
        2 & 4  \\
        1 & 1  \\
        \end{bmatrix}\right\},S=span\left\{
        \begin{bmatrix}
        -7 & 1  \\
        2 & -6  \\
        \end{bmatrix}
,        \begin{bmatrix}
        3 & 3  \\
        -4 & -2  \\
        \end{bmatrix},        \begin{bmatrix}
        2 & -8  \\
        1 & 7  \\
        \end{bmatrix}\right\}$

**EDITED:**

For $T$:

$$c_1        \begin{bmatrix}
        2  \\
        0  \\
        1 \\
        3
        \end{bmatrix}+c_2\begin{bmatrix}
        1  \\
        9  \\
        6 \\
        2
        \end{bmatrix}+c_3\begin{bmatrix}
        2  \\
        4  \\
        1 \\
        1
        \end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix}
        x  \\
        y  \\
        z \\
        w
        \end{bmatrix}$$

Solving this linear system of equations we get:
$$c1+0c_2+0c_3=\frac{x-y}{2}$$
$$0c_1+c_2+0c_3=\frac{x+2z}{11}$$
$$0c_1+0c_2+c_3=\frac{11y-2z+x}{22}$$
$$0c_1+0c_2+0c_3=\frac{11y-3z-15x+11w}{11}$$

The system is inconsistent, and elements of $T$ don't span $\mathcal{M_{2\times 2}}(\mathbb{R})$.

Elements are linearly independent since $c_1=c_2=c_3=0$ in the system:
$$2c_1+c_2+2c_3=0$$
$$0c_1+c_2+2c_3=0$$
$$c_1+6c_2+c_3=0$$
$$3c_1+2c_2+c_3=0$$

In order to find a basis of $T$, it is necessary to expand it.
How to expand it to $\mathbb{R^4}$?

Similar for $S$:
$$c_1+0c_2+0c_3=\frac{-1639y-1441x}{8448}$$
$$0c_1+c_2+0c_3=\frac{4312y+616x}{33792}$$
$$0c_1+0c_2+c_3=\frac{-77y-11x}{1056}$$
$$0c_1+0c_2+0c_3=\frac{2387y+253x+6248}{3696}$$

System is inconsistent, and elements of $S$ don't span $\mathbb{R^4}$.
Elements in $S$ are linearly independent since $c_1=c_2=c_3=0$ in:
$$-7c_1+3c_2+2c_3=0$$
$$c_1+3c_2-8c_3=0$$
$$2c_1-4c_2+c_3=0$$
$$-6c_1-2c_2+7c_3=0$$

To find a basis, it is necessary to expand $S$.

How to expand $S$ to $\mathbb{R^4}$?

Comment: I have voted to close this question as it lacks context. Please consider editing your question to improve it, otherwise it could be closed.

Answer (score 0):

To find a basis for $T$, we have to bring the following matrix in reduced row echelon form.

$$\begin{bmatrix}
2 & 0 & 1 & 3 \\
1 & 9 & 6 & 2 \\
2 & 4 & 1 & 1\
\end{bmatrix}$$

This gives us:
$$\begin{bmatrix}
1  & 0   & 0   & \dfrac{23}{22} \\
 0   & 1   & 0   & \dfrac{-1}{2} \\
 0   & 0   & 1   & \dfrac{10}{11} \\
\end{bmatrix}$$

These rows are a basis for $T$ because linear combinations of linear combinations of rows are linear combinations of rows.

The dimension of $T$ is $3$.

We can do the same for $S$ and find that the rows of

$$\begin{bmatrix}
1  & 0   & 0   & \dfrac{23}{22} \\
 0   & 1   & 0   & \dfrac{-1}{2} \\
 0   & 0   & 1   & \dfrac{10}{11} \\
\end{bmatrix}$$

are also a basis for $S$.

The dimension of $S$ is $3$.

This means that $S = T$ and that $S + T = S = T = S \cap T$ and $\dim (S) = \dim (T) = \dim (S+T) = \dim (S \cap T) = 3$.